# How can I restart a php script if it freezes?

Tags: php, shell, concurrency, parallel-processing, cron

It runs "some sort of deamon".

In fact my bootstrap file looks like this:

```
<?
$command = "php -f httpdocs/shell/run.php -- -job search/updater::run";
while(true) {
  passthru($command);
}
```

Unfortunately what is going on after passthru involves some heavily buggy stuff, and from sometime to time a library freezes. I debugged using the tick function and it turned out it was some sort of waiting `while(!feof` on an external http resource....

However I would like to dispatch the process and everything the while loop finishes touch a file.

When the timestamp gets outdated, I want to kill the process and restart it.

However passthru is blocking, so it won't get to there in that script.

I need to somehow dispatch it into the background and have a loop which continuously watches whether its still running or the files modification timestamp gets outdated and kills the old process and starts a new one, or just start a new one.

How can I do this or is there a better/easier solution?

Comment: Set a propper timeout for the network functions. That is much easier and more elegant.

Comment: it is not a timeout issue, it just freezes. for days. i don not want to debug the problem since it is a huge legacy code whcih will be replaced, but for the time beeing i need to keep it running somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in fact better to solve the problem rather than to work around it.
in my case I was dealing with 3rd party code. however phps tick handling function gave me the possibility to pinpoint the correct code part and the problem was right on the php.net homepage as a big fat warning, along with the solution.

It has nothing to do with timeouts but with the behaviour of this function on broken sockets.

> Warning If a connection opened by fsockopen() wasn't closed by the
>   server, feof() will hang. To workaround this, see below example:
>
> Example #1 Handling timeouts with feof()
>
> return feof($fp); }
>
> /* Assuming $fp is previously opened by fsockopen() */
>
> $start = NULL; $timeout = ini_get('default_socket_timeout');
>
> while(!safe_feof($fp, $start) && (microtime(true) - $start) <
>   $timeout) {  /* Handle */ } ?>

Answer (score 1):

I did a stall detection on a command line script not too long ago.  It sounds like a few things need to happen...

1) Add a timeout for the http:// request within that command you're running

2) You can monitor it using a while() statement, you'll have to use something like this:

```
$stillRunning = true;
while ($stillRunning) {
    exec('ps -ef | grep httpdocs/shell/run.php', $processes); //will get all process which contain the path to the file

    //loop through all processes to determine if it's still running.  If so, grab the process ID and kill it'

    exec('kill '.$processId);

    //if it's still there, this will do the job
    if ($this->_ifProcessExists($processId)) {
        exec('kill -9 '.$processId);
    }

    sleep(2);
}
```

Here's the class I built to detect stalling to meet our needs...

```
<?php
/**
 * GMC Management Class
 * 
 */

class GMC {

    private $executablePath = '/usr/local/PNetT/PNetTCNetClient',
            $outPath = '/usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/',
            $workflowPath = '',
            $graphicPath = '',
            $logRecipient = 'my@email.com',
            $stalledThreshold = 10, //in seconds
            $originalProcesses = array(),
            $processes = array(),
            $log = array();

    public function __construct () {
        $this->workflowPath = $this->outPath.'workflows/';
        $this->graphicPath = $this->outPath.'graphics/';
    }

    /**
     * Adds an image to the GMC graphics directory
     * 
     * @param string $imgPath The absolute path of the image to add
     */
    public function addImage ($imgPath) {
        exec('cp '.$imgPath.' '.$this->graphicPath);
    }

    /**
     * Determines if a process is stalled
     */
    public function isStalled ($processes = false) {
        if ($processes === false) {
            $processes = $this->_getProcesses();
            $this->originalProcesses = $processes;
        }

        foreach ($processes as $process) {
            if (array_key_exists('duration', $process) && $process['duration'] <= (time() - $this->stalledThreshold)) {
                $this->_addLog("detected #".$process['processId']." as a stalled process");
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Fixes GMC's being stalled
     * Will also report the document that caused the stall
     */
    public function fixStalled () {
        $this->_restart();

        $this->reportLog();
    }

    /**
     * Sends the log to the development team for review
     */
    public function reportLog () {
        $body = "Here's a report how GMC was handled during this last stall:

Oldest process:\n
        ID | COMMAND\n";

        $oldest = $this->_getOldestProcess();
        $body .= "        ".$oldest['processId']." | ".$oldest['command']."\n";

        $body .= "
Logs:\n";

        foreach ($this->log as $log) {
            $body .= "        ".$log."\n";
        }

        $body .= "
Processes:\n
        ID | COMMAND\n";

        foreach ($this->processes as $process) {
            $body .= "        ".$process['processId']." | ".$process['command']."\n";
        }

        mail($this->logRecipient, 'GMC Stalled Report', $body);
    }

    /**
     * Restarts GMC
     * Must be conducted after GMC's stalled processes have been killed
     */
    private function _restart () {
        //kill all GMC processes
        foreach ($this->_getProcesses(true) as $process) {
            $this->_killProcess($process['processId']);
        }

        //restart GMC
        exec('bash /usr/local/PNetT/pnet.sh');

        $this->_addLog("GMC has been restarted");
    }

    /**
     * Restarts GMC
     * Must be conducted after GMC's stalled processes have been killed
     */
    private function _getOldestProcess () {
        $oldest = array(
            'timestamp' => 0,
            'processId' => 0
        );
        foreach ($this->_getProcesses() as $process) {
            if ($process['user'] == 'wwwuser' && $process['duration'] > $oldest['timestamp']) {
                $oldest = array(
                    'timestamp' => $process['duration'],
                    'processId' => $process['processId']
                );
            }
        }

        return $this->processes[$oldest['processId']];
    }

    /**
     * Get a list of all GMC processes
     */
    private function _getProcesses ($newList = false) {
        if ($newList == true || count($this->processes) == 0) {
            //exec('ps -ef | grep GMC', $processes);
            //sample processes for testing, above command is for live usage
            $processes = array(
                'ps -ef | grep GMC',
                'wwwuser   1767 31199  0 12:40 ?        00:00:00 /scripts/GMC/PNetT-5.1-SP1/PNetTCNetClient.bin -o /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/workflows/master_ppo_sob_3col.wfd -e PDF -f /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-LP2069 Solution PPO 1500-15-20 MOCKUP_temp.pdf -useincluded * -difDataInput1 /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-LP2069 Solution PPO 1500-15-20 MOCKUP.txt -difDataInput2 /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-LP2069 Solution PPO 1500-15-20 MOCKUP-table.txt',
                'wwwuser   2364  1207  0 12:41 ?        00:00:00 /scripts/GMC/PNetT-5.1-SP1/PNetTCNetClient.bin -o /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/workflows/master_ppo_sob_3col.wfd -e PDF -f /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-LP2045 mock up_temp.pdf -useincluded * -difDataInput1 /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-LP2045 mock up.txt -difDataInput2 /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-LP2045 mock up-table.txt',
                'wwwuser   2465  2378  0 12:42 ?        00:00:00 /scripts/GMC/PNetT-5.1-SP1/PNetTCNetClient.bin -o /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/workflows/master_ppo_sob_3col.wfd -e PDF -f /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-PBARR Test 12-20_temp.pdf -useincluded * -difDataInput1 /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-PBARR Test 12-20.txt -difDataInput2 /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-PBARR Test 12-20-table.txt',
                'wwwuser  19370  7900  0 13:17 ?        00:00:00 /scripts/GMC/PNetT-5.1-SP1/PNetTCNetClient.bin -o /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/workflows/master_ppo_sob_3col.wfd -e PDF -f /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-LP2069_temp.pdf -useincluded * -difDataInput1 /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-LP2069.txt -difDataInput2 /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-LP2069-table.txt',
                'root     19948 19508  0 13:18 pts/6    00:00:00 grep GMC',
                'wwwuser  26685 17061  0 12:25 ?        00:00:00 /scripts/GMC/PNetT-5.1-SP1/PNetTCNetClient.bin -o /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/workflows/diff_report.wfd -e PDF -f /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-LP2069 Solution PPO 1500-15-20 MOCKUP_differences.pdf -useincluded * -difDataInput1 /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-LP2069 Solution PPO 1500-15-20 MOCKUP-report.txt -difDataInput2 /usr/local/PNetT/tmpData/SOB/Master PPO-LP2069 Solution PPO 1500-15-20 MOCKUP-table-report.txt',
                'root     32017     1 89 May03 ?        12-18:02:22 /scripts/GMC/PNetT-5.1-SP1/PNetTNetServer.bin -tempdir /usr/local/GMC/PNetT-5.1-SP1/tmpData -D'
            );

            $this->processes = array();
            foreach ($processes as $idx => $process) {
                if ($idx > 1) {
                    $pieces = preg_split("/\s+/", $process, 8);

                    //skip the grep filter process
                    if ($pieces[7] != 'grep GMC') {
                        $this->processes[$pieces[1]] = array(
                            'user' => $pieces[0],
                            'processId' => $pieces[1],
                            'duration' => strtotime($pieces[4]),
                            'command' => $pieces[7]
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->processes;
    }

    /**
     * Kills a process
     * 
     * @param int $processId The process to be killed
     */
    private function _killProcess ($processId) {
        //nicely
        exec('kill '.$processId);

        //if it's still there, this will do the job
        if ($this->_ifProcessExists($processId)) {
            exec('kill -9 '.$processId);

            $this->_addLog("process #".$processId." wasn't nicely killed, I had to force it");
        } else {
            $this->_addLog("process #".$processId." was nicely killed");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determines if a process is still running
     * 
     * @param int $processId The process to be checked
     */
    private function _ifProcessExists ($processId) {
        exec('ps '.$processId, $return);

        return count($return) > 1;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a message to the log
     */
    private function _addLog ($message) {
        $this->log[] = $message;
    }
}

?>
```